# draw arrow drag start an element drag end another

Tags: javascript, css

Any ideas about drawing arrow with "drag start and end" with css/javascript like this yellow arrow here in video

https://youtu.be/4QaEE8noGdE?t=32

alrdy googled but I don't find the good keywords, I always get arrows between 2 elements for charts, never an "animated" arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isnt something premade for this Problem, but you can simply check for your mouse-events.

For example, when you click with your mouse (Event mousedown) you can initiate the Arrow at the pointer position, and when you drag your mouse (Event onmousemove) you can change the Tip of the Arrow, pointing to the new position.

I just did an small example with a bad image, but i hope you get

```js
let down = false;

let initPos;
let arrow;
window.onmousedown = (ev)=>{
    down = true;
    let x = ev.clientX;
    let y = ev.clientY;
    initPos = {x,y};
    arrow = document.createElement("img");
    arrow.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Arrow_right.svg";
    // arrow.style.height = "30px";
    arrow.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    arrow.style.position = "absolute";
    arrow.style.left = x+"px";
    arrow.style.top = y+"px";
    

};

window.onmouseup = (ev)=>{
    down = false;
    document.body.innerHTML = "";

};

window.onmousemove = (ev)=>{
    if(down){
        let x = ev.clientX;
        let y = ev.clientY;
        
        let x2 = initPos.x;
        let y2 = initPos.y;
        
        let theta = Math.atan2(y-y2,x-x2);
        arrow.style.width = dist(x,y,x2,y2)+"px";
        arrow.style.transform = "rotate(" + theta + "rad)";
        document.body.appendChild(arrow);
    }
};


function dist(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```